HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() request not reaching the endpoint destination
When I take user data and pass it to a command so I can pass it to the endpoint (controller method), the response doesn't even point me in the direction of the specified endpoint. I'm using Blazor and.net 8 and I want to create a new reservation. It also directs me when I try to access the endpoint without the command.
    public async Task<Result<ReservationDto>?> CreateReservationsAsync(string name, string surname, DateOnly birthday, string ssn)
    {
        var reservationCommand = new CreateReservationCommand
        {
            Name = name,
            Surname = surname,
            Birthday = birthday,
            Ssn = ssn
        };
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/admin/Reservation/create", reservationCommand);
        return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Result<ReservationDto>>();
    }

  [HttpPost("create")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReservationAsync([FromBody] CreateReservationCommand command)
  {
      var result = await Mediator?.Send(command)!;

      if (result.Failed)
      {
          return BadRequest(result);
      }

      return Ok(result.Value);
  }

I am expectin to direct me to the specified endpoind, with the command provided from front end.
Also, when I change the controller method to this, it works, but i want to use the above type of method:
 [HttpPost("create")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReservationAsync()
 {
     var requestBody = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
     var command = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateReservationCommand>(requestBody);

     var result = await Mediator?.Send(command)!;

     if (result.Failed)
     {
         return BadRequest(result);
     }

     return Ok(result.Value);
 }


Your codes worked well in my side, could you pls share more details about how you send the http client? Or a minimal sample for reproducing your issue? I test with a .net 8 blazor web assembly app and a web api application. https://i.sstatic.net/M111U6pB.png

https://imgur.com/a/EMqquWQ

Can you please help confirm whether you are using a blazor app(.net 8 blazor wasm? blazor web app?  server side rendered/client side rendered/auto rendered? ) to send http request to the API(.net 8 webapi or mvc?)?

I am using blazor web api, .net8 webapi, i work on server side, but when i run it, i run the client side of the blazor

Please bear with me, but what is  "blazor web api"? I never know it before...
